# Getting the "mean value" for a column in a database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database row of entries, with a common column that contains a string value, "L" "LV" "LRW" and "AD". Asssuming that there are a numerous number of these fields, with multiple values of this nature. Is there a way inside a SQL query to return the most occurring value of this column (essentially, the mean average), over returning all the column entries, or should I delegate this higher up in the development chain?

Edit: Per requests, here's an example setup of what the table actually looks like:

```
+------------+---------+
|    Ent1    |  value  |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | L       |
| 2          | L       |
| 3          | LV      |
| 4          | AD      |
| 5          | AD      |
| 6          | L       |
| 7          | LRW     |
| 8          | L       |
+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Not clear at all.  Post representative sample of your relevant data and the desired result.

Comment: Are you trying to get the most common value from a single column? Or from multiple columns at the same time? Please show some code so we can understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: "most occurring value (essentially, the mean average)" . . . At least one of use is very confused by this.

Comment: You are asking for the *mode* of a column. *Mean* and *average* are the same thing, and contrast with the mode. For example, in a list of `1 1 1 2 3 8` you will have a mean or average of 16/6 but a mode of 1. Would you consider changing the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the value that occurs the most, you can use the COUNT() aggregate function to get the number of appearances, and limit your result set to one row:

```
SELECT columnName, COUNT(*) AS numAppearances
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnName
ORDER BY numAppearances DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

By ordering in descending order, you're effectively putting the values with most appearances first, and you can limit by 1 to get only that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT myColumn, COUNT(*) AS amount 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY myColumn 
ORDER BY amount DESC 
LIMIT 1
```